# Unity AssetBundles via AppStoreConnect SIGABRT

Tags: unity-game-engine, app-store, app-store-connect, assetbundle, on-demand-resources

I'm trying to build a Unity Game using AssetBundles and I want to distribute them using the Apple AppStore. But the app crashes with an SIGABRT error as soon as I try to use the asset bundles.

I followed [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AppThinning.html) instruction and adapted it to fit our needs.
When loding `request.error` returns an empty string (not null as it would be expected).

Eventhough `myLoadedAssetBundle.GetAllAssetNames()` returns the full list of assets as expected.

The asset bundles show up in XCode (see Image below).

After Uploading the archive to AppStoreConnect On-Demand-Resources is marked as "yes" but in contrast to the documentation the number of assets is not shown.

- Mac Studio M1 Ultra
- MacOS 13.0.1 (22A400)
- Unity 2020.3.39f (intel)
- XCode Version 14.1 (14B47b)
- Visual Studio for Mac 17.4.1 (build 28)
- iPad (10th Generation)
- iPadOS 16.1.1 (20B101)

---

[image: XCode Image]

creating Asset Bundles:

```cs
public class CreateAssetBundles
{
    static string iosAssetBundleDirectory = "AssetBundles/iOS";
    [InitializeOnLoadMethod]
    static void SetupResourcesBuild()
    {
        UnityEditor.iOS.BuildPipeline.collectResources += CollectResources;
    }

    static UnityEditor.iOS.Resource[] CollectResources()
    {
        var bundles = AssetDatabase.GetAllAssetBundleNames ();
        
        var reslist = new List<UnityEditor.iOS.Resource> ();
        foreach (var b in bundles)
        {
            reslist.Add(new UnityEditor.iOS.Resource(b,Path.Combine(iosAssetBundleDirectory, b)).AddOnDemandResourceTags(b));
        }

        return reslist.ToArray();
    }

    [MenuItem ("Assets/Build AssetBundles/iOS")]
    static void BuildiOS ()
    {
        EnableDisableAtlas (true);
        
        var options = BuildAssetBundleOptions.None;

        bool shouldCheckODR = EditorUserBuildSettings.activeBuildTarget == BuildTarget.iOS;

#if UNITY_TVOS
        shouldCheckODR |= EditorUserBuildSettings.activeBuildTarget == BuildTarget.tvOS;
#endif

        if (shouldCheckODR)
        {
#if IOS_APP_BUNDLE
            if (PlayerSettings.iOS.useOnDemandResources)
            {
                options |= BuildAssetBundleOptions.UncompressedAssetBundle;
            }
#endif

#if ENABLE_IOS_APP_SLICING
            options |= BuildAssetBundleOptions.UncompressedAssetBundle;
#endif

            if (!Directory.Exists(iosAssetBundleDirectory))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(iosAssetBundleDirectory);
            }
        }
        var ret = BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundles (iosAssetBundleDirectory,
                                        options,
                                        BuildTarget.iOS);
        EnableDisableAtlas (false);
    }
}
```

loading Asset Bundles

```cs
    public override IEnumerator DownloadAssetBundleAsync (string bundleName, StringParameter statusParameter, Image progressBar, float remainingPercentiles)
    {
        OnDemandResourcesRequest request = OnDemandResources.PreloadAsync(new string[] { bundleName });
        while (!request.isDone)
        {
            yield return null;
        }

        if (request.error != null && request.error != "")
        {
            //handle error
        }
        DownloadFinished?.Invoke(bundleName);
        yield break;

    }
   
    public override IEnumerator LoadAssetBundleFromFileAsync (string bundleName, StringParameter statusParameter, Image progressBar, float remainingPercentiles, bool checkOutdated)
    {
        var filepath = "res://" + bundleName;

        var bundleLoadRequest = AssetBundle.LoadFromFileAsync(filepath);
        yield return bundleLoadRequest;
        while (!bundleLoadRequest.isDone)
        {
            yield return null;
        }
        var myLoadedAssetBundle = bundleLoadRequest.assetBundle;

        if (myLoadedAssetBundle == null)
        {
            //Handle error
        }
        loadedAssetBundle = myLoadedAssetBundle;
    }
```

SIGABRT

```
Incident Identifier: [REMOVED]
Beta Identifier:     [REMOVED]
Hardware Model:      iPad13,18
Process:             [REMOVED] [547]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/[REMOVED]
Identifier:          [REMOVED]
Version:             0.9.1 (21)
AppStoreTools:       14C17
AppVariant:          1:iPad13,18:16
Beta:                YES
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           [REMOVED] [694]

Date/Time:           2022-12-12 13:45:12.5058 +0100
Launch Time:         2022-12-12 13:45:05.0791 +0100
OS Version:          iPhone OS 16.1.1 (20B101)
Release Type:        User
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  35

Application Specific Information:
abort() called


Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                         0x1d1171e88 __exceptionPreprocess + 164
1   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x1ca5178d8 objc_exception_throw + 60
2   Foundation                             0x1cb6259b0 -[_NSInlineData length] + 0
3   UnityFramework                         0x10fc45370 AssetCatalogFile::Read(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, void*, unsigned long long*, FileReadFlags) + 88806256 (AssetCatalogFileSystem.mm:52)
4   UnityFramework                         0x10fc45264 AssetCatalogFileSystemHandler::Read(FileEntryData&, VFS::FileSize, unsigned long long, void*, unsigned long long*, FileReadFlags) + 88805988 (AssetCatalogFileSystem.mm:178)
5   UnityFramework                         0x10f0c1074 FileAccessor::Read(VFS::FileSize, unsigned long long, void*, unsigned long long*, FileReadFlags) + 76730484 (VirtualFileSystem.cpp:1011)
6   UnityFramework                         0x10f6ad6c4 ArchiveStorageReader::ReadFromStorage(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, void*, unsigned long long*) + 82941636 (ArchiveStorageReader.cpp:587)
7   UnityFramework                         0x10f6a5f80 ArchiveStorageReader::Read(VFS::FileSize, unsigned long long, void*, unsigned long long*, FileReadFlags) + 82911104 (ArchiveStorageReader.cpp:173)
8   UnityFramework                         0x10f6a5d60 ArchiveReadFile::Read(VFS::FileSize, unsigned long long, void*, unsigned long long*, FileReadFlags) + 82910560 (ArchiveReadFile.cpp:42)
9   UnityFramework                         0x10f6a4240 ArchiveFileSystem::Read(FileEntryData&, VFS::FileSize, unsigned long long, void*, unsigned long long*, FileReadFlags) + 82903616 (ArchiveFileSystem.cpp:267)
10  UnityFramework                         0x10f0c1074 FileAccessor::Read(VFS::FileSize, unsigned long long, void*, unsigned long long*, FileReadFlags) + 76730484 (VirtualFileSystem.cpp:1011)
11  UnityFramework                         0x10f61714c File::Read(VFS::FileSize, void*, unsigned long, FileReadFlags) + 82325836 (FileVFS.cpp:443)
12  UnityFramework                         0x10f2b1ecc AsyncReadManagerThreaded::PumpRequests(dynamic_array<AsyncReadCommand*, 0ul>&, dynamic_array<AsyncReadCommand*, 0ul>&) + 78765772 (AsyncReadManagerThreaded.cpp:169)
13  UnityFramework                         0x10f2b191c AsyncReadManagerThreaded::ThreadEntry() + 78764316 (AsyncReadManagerThreaded.cpp:248)
14  UnityFramework                         0x10f2b12d0 AsyncReadManagerThreaded::StaticThreadEntry(void*) + 78762704 (AsyncReadManagerThreaded.cpp:118)
15  UnityFramework                         0x10f6c6994 Thread::RunThreadWrapper(void*) + 83044756 (Thread.cpp:81)
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x21d84b6cc _pthread_start + 148
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x21d84aba4 thread_start + 8
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Feyyyyy from the Unity-Forum](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1319641/loading-asset-from-an-asset-bundle-crashes-on-ios.html) points out:
When subdeviding downloading and reading AssetBundles into different functions, be sure to keep `request`.

If `request` gets out of scope, the AssetBundle is garbage collected and the App crashes when trying to read the data.

The problem can for example be fixed by pushing request into a static list

```cs
    private static List<OnDemandResourcesRequest> requestsList = new List<OnDemandResourcesRequest>();

    public override IEnumerator DownloadAssetBundleAsync (string bundleName, StringParameter statusParameter, Image progressBar, float remainingPercentiles)
    {
        OnDemandResourcesRequest request = OnDemandResources.PreloadAsync(new string[] { bundleName });
        while (!request.isDone)
        {
            yield return null;
        }

        if (request.error != null && request.error != "")
        {
            //handle error
        }
        requestsList.Add(request);      // Push into list to prevent GC
        DownloadFinished?.Invoke(bundleName);
        yield break;
    }
```